# How to Show PDF View when user open website on Browser Mobile ? Jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Pleas Help..

In my project web on Page Magazine i have FlipBook Funtion, and i want when user open page magazine on mobile browser flipbook not showing, but show PDF view.. please help

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/226/top-5-best-open-source-pdf-generation-libraries-for-php

and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: Stack overflow is not a free code design and writing service. Please show us what you have attempted and explain why it is wrong.